# Get host ip android

Tags: java, android, ip-address

Tried to do my homework, but can't figure it out.

I am making an app that will run on a phone that stays connected to my home wifi 24/7.  I want it to detect the host ip and track any changes, but I can't get the code to work.  I found the InetAddress class, that seems like what I need, but the following code throws a generic exception "something bad is going wrong", I don't know how to pin it down, since its not the UnknownHostException that the method throws in the documentation:

```
public void getIP(View view) {
    isNetOK();
    getLocalIpAddress();

}

public void isNetOK() {
    //get connectivity manager
            connMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            //call getActiveNetworkInfo method of connMan, returns a networkInfo object
            NetworkInfo netInfo = connMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo !=null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                setViewText("net_stat", "Network Connected"); 
                netOK = true;
            } else {
                setViewText("net_stat", "Network Unavailable");
            }
}

public void getLocalIpAddress() {
     isNetOK();
     if (netOK) {

         try{

          InetAddress ownIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
          localIP = ownIP.toString();
          }catch (UnknownHostException e){
          setViewText("ip_view", "Error: unknown host");
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              setViewText("ip_view", "Something bad is going wrong");
          }

     }
```

isNetOK works just fine, I have been calling it separately for a day or so.

Can someone point the way on why this code won't work?
Is this the best approach?  My goal is to link a server at home with a domain name I got at GoDaddy.  My ip address is dynamic, but only changes every few months, or when the power goes out.  I want an app that can check the ip once every now and then (6 hours?), and notify me if it changes so I can update the DNS.  I know, hacky and slow, etc but its really just for private use and to see if I can make it work.

**EDIT 1**

I tried the method in budcopter's answer below, and finally got some code working with some changes:

```
    public void getLocalIpAddress() {
     if (netOK) {
         try{
             WifiManager WiMan = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
             WifiInfo wifiInfo = WiMan.getConnectionInfo();
             int address = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
             String ipAddress = (String) Integer.toString(address);
             setViewText("ip_view", ipAddress);
          } /*catch (UnknownHostException e){
              setViewText("ip_view", "Error: unknown host");
          } */catch (Exception ex) {
              setViewText("ip_view", "Something bad is going wrong");
          }
     }
```

This returns a valid int, ten digits long.  However, when I check it against whatismyip.com, they are not even close to being the same.  The phone's LAN address is 192.168.1.110, our external ip is 75.xx.xx.xxx, the int returned is 1812048064.  This same number returns even if I power cycle the WiFi radio.  Any idea what number the WifiManager system service is giving me?

Also, I will add a check to prevent requesting the address if WiFi is disabled, but that is trivial at the moment.

Comment: This won't solve your problem anyway, since the phone does not know the router's **external** IP address, and **can not know it** without asking the router or something outside.   Basically, you'll need the programmatic equivalent of hitting one of those IP finder sites.  You might find it easier to run a custom service on the router itself.

Comment: Thank you Chris Stratton.  Any idea what the code is returning?  I'll look into other options, I tried setting the phone to be DMZ through the router, no change.  I understand what you are saying, I'll start looking for programmatic tools through one of those sites, I don't know how to make my program interact with a simple consumer wifi router appliance.

Comment: DMZ would not change anything, because the phone is still getting traffic routed via the local network.  I was actually suggesting more putting the publish-ip-update daemon on the router rather than the phone.  If the router or cable modem has a status webpage though, you could probably scrape it with the phone and look for the external it receives from the upstream DHCP server.  Of course if you are behind carrier NAT even that won't be an externally visible address.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public void getLocalIpAddress() {
 // remove it, duplicated call
 // isNetOK();
 if (netOK) {

     try{
         WifiInfo wifiInfo = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
         int address = info.getIpAddress();

         String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(address);
         setViewText("ip_view", ipAddress);
      } catch (UnknownHostException e){
          setViewText("ip_view", "Error: unknown host");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          setViewText("ip_view", "Something bad is going wrong");
      }

 }
```

And don't forget the userpermisson in you androidmainfest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Of Course, I did it in my project. Here are source code:http://code.google.com/p/wifi-scanner/source/browse/src/com/shixunaoyou/wifiscanner/wifi/ConnectionInfoDialog.java

Comment: I'm having trouble with this method.  I can't find class mWifiManager (in eclipse, or in the docs), but I can find WifiManager.  When I try "WifiInfo wifiInfo = WifiManager.getConnectionInfo();" it tells me I can't make static reference to non-static method getConnectionInfo().

Comment: Also, Formatter.formatIpAddress is deprecated, so I removed that line.  I'm just going to store the ip as an int, that will be fine, maybe easier, for comparing a stored value over time.

Comment: Regardless if this "works" or not to find the local IP address, that is not what needs to be discovered to solve the actual need.

Comment: I have completely changed my approach, so just one final observation to this question.  The above code from buptcoder returns a number, but it is neither the phone's internal ip nor the router's public ip, its just a ten digit int.  I'm not really sure what it is.

Comment: Do you use Formatter.formatIpAddress(address) to convert the number to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx?